# How to select the child object of an object by variable reference in PHP?

Tags: php, class, object

I have an object in PHP (in my case, a CakePHP model), that has child objects, eg. the structure of `$this->Model1->Model2`.

I am aware that the above syntax is the correct way to reference the object, but if I have obtained the name of `Model2` via another process, so it is a string variable. How can I reference it using this variable, similar to as follows:

```
$model_name = 'Model2';
$this->Model1[ $model_name ]->run_function();
```

Now clearly this array-style of selecting the object/class doesn't work, but is there a similar method I should be using? Or is there better coding practice that wouldn't result in this issue all together?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you looking for this?

```
$property = 'myProperty';
$object->{$property};
```

Comment: That is exactly right! Thank you, I have never even seen a similar notation. You were so quick I can't even flag you correct yet.

I didn't actually realise that it was this simple, what is the relevance of the braces when, on testing just now, they don't appear to be required.

Answer (score 1):

Just do like this:

```
$this->Model1->$model_name->run_function();
```